# Mongoose: $addToSet doesn't check for duplicates

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, duplicates

Could you please take a look at this code? I have duplicates.

Here's the schema:

```
var Account = new Schema({
     username: String,
     votes:[
       {                                            
         resId: String,                                 
         upvoted:[String]                                                           
       }
     ]                                                                          
 });
```

I'm trying to add an item into **votes**

```
var id = 'a';
var resId = 'b';

users.update({'_id':id},                
    {
         '$addToSet': {'votes': {'resId': resId}}
    }
);
```

The problem is that after two updates I get two of them when I need only one:

```
[
 {
    'username': 'Fat Gandalf',
    'votes': [
       {
          '_id': objectID('11111111111111111111111'),
          'resId': 'b',
          'upvoted': []
       }
    ]
},
{
    'username': 'Fat Gandalf',
    'votes': [
       {
          '_id': objectID('2222222222222222222222'),
          'resId': 'b',
          'upvoted': []
       }
    ]
 }
]
```

How come $addToSet doesn't check for dupes here? Is there a workaround for this? Tried **$push** and it didn't work either. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Added '_id:' false; to schema and now it works just fine!

Comment: SInce "res" and "upvoted" are two values it's "both" that comprise as a "set", and therefore any variation in those two values is indeed a new entry. Additionally there is `_id` that mongoose automatically adds unless you specify a separate schema for the array content and use the `{ "_id": false }` option. At any rate you want `$push` and you need to test for the "resId" value either present or not, i.e `{ "votes.resId": { "$ne": "b" } },{ "$push": { "votes": { "resId": "b", "upvoted": [] } }`. Lot's of examples for "upvoting" systems if you look.